# Compiler keeps saying Array is Null (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, arrays

I've declared a global array, which was initialized in a method. The problem is, I need to use the length of the array to pass it in as an argument for another method, but when I do, i get a message saying the array is null. I understand why it is null, but I am not sure on what the solution to this could be?

Code example:

```
Public class Example A{
 int element;   
int [] NumArray;

element = NumArray.length -1


}

public Method(){
NumArray = new int [length]
}
```

The error comes at the line: element = NumArray.Length -1

Like I said, I understand why it is null, but I dont know how to resolve it, because the initialization of the array MUST occur in the method due to the structure of my code.

Is there any way where i can grab the length of the array from the method and return that in the main method?

Comment: it gives error because you did not put any value inside array

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned that it is populated with values, and i have written print statements to verify that it does contain the data i have initialized it with

Comment: BTW: read about java naming convention

Comment: The compiler is right!

Comment: Umm, this code is a bit strange: `Example A` should cause a syntax error since class-names can't contain spaces, `Method()` is not contained in any `class`, `Method()` is not a method since it has not declared a return-type (it might be a constructor in a `class Method`),....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
int [] NumArray;
element = NumArray.length -1
```

**Details:**
you declared **NumArray** but never initialize it until the constructor is called (this is 100% ok) but the next line you are trying to get `NumArray.length` of the non initialized array and that is the reason...

**Solution:**
place this line inside the constructor, it belongs to it

```
element = NumArray.length -1;
```

like

```
public Method(){
    NumArray = new int [length]
    element = NumArray.length -1;
}
```

Comment: ahhh i see. Thank you so much! But would that not just return to me the index number as opposed to the actual value in that array? Do you know i can return that value?

Comment: nop...the value of the variable  __element__ can be accessed by others too... I hope that was your question...